# Formulario html no me deja subir informacion a bdd en phoMyAdmin

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Estoy trabajando en un formulario html para que me envie datos por el metodo POST a un archivo registrarAcursos.php pero no me deja ingresar los datos que obtengo con la primer sql, me sale un error que no se puediron mandar los datos.

ya busque error comparando con otros archivos de verificar iguales y no encuentra nada.

```html
                <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left"  action="registrarAcursos.php" method="POST">
                
                <h4>Busca el Alumno</h4>
                <p class="font-gray-dark">
                  Seleciona el alumno que quieres registrar al : <?php echo $_SESSION['nombre_c'] ?> .
                </p>
                <div class="col-md-8 center-margin">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Ingresa el Nombre De Usuario Del alumno que quieres ingresar</label>
                      <input name="usuario" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
                    </div>
                </div>     
        <center>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Agregar Alumno</button>
        </center>


                  <?php
                $ID = $_SESSION['id_c'];

$mensaje = $_GET['msj'];
if ($mensaje == "si"){
    header('Location:aggAlumnos.php') ;
} 
if($mensaje == "no"){
    echo "Usuario incorrecto";
}
if ($mensaje == "ya"){
    
    
    echo "El usuario no existe";

}
?>
                </form>
```

y este es el código php

```html
<?php

include("conexion.php");

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];

$sql="SELECT USUARIO FROM USUARIOS WHERE USUARIO='$usuario'";

$result= $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows>0){

     $IDUSUARIO = $row['IDUSUARIO'];
        $NOMBRE = $row['NOMBRE'];
  $IDC = $_SESSION['id_c'];
     $NOMBRE_C = $_SESSION['nombre_c'];
 
       
 $sql2 = "INSERT INTO REGISTRO(ID_ALUMNO,NOMBRE_ALUMNO,ID_CURSO,NOMBRE_CURSO)
          VALUES('$IDUSUARIO','$NOMBRE','$IDC','$NOMBRE_C')";

 $result2=$conn->query($sql2);

 if($result2 === TRUE){
        header('Location:aggAlumnos.php?msj=si') ;
 }else{
   header('Location:aggAlumnos.php?msj=no') ;
 }

}else{

header('Location:aggAlumnos.php?msj=ya') ;

}



?>
```

Comment: estás agregando session_start(); al principio de cada archivo?

Comment: haz un echo del sql2 para ver que muestra

Comment: si agregue el session_start();

Comment: el mensaje que me da es de los que tengo programadas si no se cumple la segunda sql

Comment: puedes agregar la conexion.php

Comment: después de $sql2 = "INSERT...  agrega un die($sql2); para ver que valores se asignan..

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\wamp\www\curso2.0\production\registrarAcursos.php on line 15
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0061 255784 {main}( ) ..\registrarAcursos.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\wamp\www\curso2.0\production\registrarAcursos.php on line 16
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0061 255784 {main}( ) ..\registrarAcursos.php:0
INSERT INTO REGISTRO(ID_ALUMNO,NOMBRE_ALUMNO,ID_CURSO,NOMBRE_CURSO) VALUES('','','5','POWER POINT AVANZADO ')

Comment: $row no existe. te falta el fetch.

Comment: efectivamente como dice jdev te falta el fetch.. prueba agregando despues de if($result->num_rows>0){..  $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La cosa es que sacas una variable `$row` de la nada. Deberías utilizar algún método para recorrer los resultados (foreach o while).

He aquí un ejemplo:

```html
<?php

include("conexion.php");

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];

$sql="SELECT USUARIO FROM USUARIOS WHERE USUARIO='$usuario'";

$result= $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows>0){
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
     $IDUSUARIO = $row['IDUSUARIO'];
            $NOMBRE = $row['NOMBRE'];
            $IDC = $_SESSION['id_c'];
     $NOMBRE_C = $_SESSION['nombre_c'];
 }
       
 $sql2 = "INSERT INTO REGISTRO(ID_ALUMNO,NOMBRE_ALUMNO,ID_CURSO,NOMBRE_CURSO)
          VALUES('$IDUSUARIO','$NOMBRE','$IDC','$NOMBRE_C')";

 $result2=$conn->query($sql2);

 if($result2 === TRUE){
        header('Location:aggAlumnos.php?msj=si') ;
 }else{
   header('Location:aggAlumnos.php?msj=no') ;
 }

}else{

header('Location:aggAlumnos.php?msj=ya') ;

}



?>
```